# How To Setup A Nestjs Query With TypeORM That Returns Multiple Items?

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I send this URL from Angular:

`http://localhost:3000/api/skills?category_id=2`

The question is, how do I fix my code so it retrieves all skills with a category_id of 2?

I'm not looking for the skill_id, I can fetch individual skills without a problem.  The record looks like this:

```
skill_id
skill_name
category_id
```

In the skills.controller I have this.  I've been experimenting with the @Get param but still can't call this function.  Console.log never gets called.  Also, I have no idea how to tell the service that I want all skill records that have a category_id of 2 or whatever number needed.

```
  @Get('?category_id')
  public async getSkillsByCategory(@Param('category_id') categoryId) {
    console.log('skills recordId in controller: ', categoryId.id);
    return this.skillsService.getSkillsByCategory(categoryId.id);
  }
```

In the skills.service I have this but it doesn't tell the db, Postgres, to query category_id 2.  Somehow that needs to happen but the category_id column isn't a regular param it seems.

```
  async getSkillsByCategory(categoryId) {
    console.log('categoryId in service', categoryId);
    return await this.skillsRepository.find(categoryId);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your skills root path is `http://localhost:3000/api/skills/`, change your controller to:

```
  import { ParseIntPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
  // you can use ParseIntPipe to validate if id is actually number, very useful

  @Get('category/:id')  //  or  @Get('/category/:id')
  public async getSkillsByCategory(@Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id) {
    return this.skillsService.getSkillsByCategory(id);
  }
```

And your service:

```
async getSkillsByCategory(id) {
  return await this.skillsRepository.find({ category_id: id });
}
```

And now call `http://localhost:3000/api/skills/category/2`.

Comment: Thank you but that URL didn't call that Get param. I tested your URL in Postman, faster than changing my Angular code, and the console.log in Get never got called.  It looks better than anything I've tried though :-)  By the way, this URL will retrieve skill_id 2 so my main setup works:  http://localhost:3000/api/skills/2

Comment: The end of that select query for the skill_id looks like this:  WHERE ("Skills"."skill_id" = $1) -- PARAMETERS: ["2"].   I need something like that for finding all skills with a certain category_id.

Comment: I changed your Get param and called: '/category_id/2' then I get this at the end of the select query: WHERE "Skills"."category_id" = $1 -- PARAMETERS: [null]  This seems to be getting close.  At least it is calling that Get function now.

Comment: Wait a minute. I will setup project and test

Comment: This works!  Get('/category_id/:id')  Thanks for getting me on the right track!  Edit your post and I'll mark it as the answer. :-)

Comment: It's good. I test on my project and actually @Get(`category/:id`) works as well) What about your service?

Comment: Same service as yours.  category/ shouldn't be the same as category_id/

Comment: What do you mean by `category/ shouldn't be the same as category_id/ `?

Comment: Yes, category_id is a db column or field.  I have nothing in the db called category.  If I change Get back to Get('/category/:id') I get:  404, error: "Not Found", message: "Cannot GET /api/skills/category_id/1"}

Comment: But your path in API doesn't relate to DB table. You can use `category/:id` or `something/:id` or something else. It is important to get value from `:id` and pass it to skillsService. Could you update your questions with latest code (especially controller), please?

Comment: Vlad, look at my skills table columns above.  There is nothing called category.  The column I want is called "category_id" and that works in your suggested code.  Category does not.  I'm confused as to why you are confused.  In Postgres we have to use the underline, not camel case.  I can't use categoryId.

Comment: I know about table, and I know that category_id is a column. I am talking about controller and @Get('category/:id'), not about database query. `@Get('category/:id')` should perfectly work for you, and it is not related to your table or column. Please, look in my code.

Comment: What does 'category/' refer to if not the db column?  It doesn't work for me and I don't understand how it could work.  In Postman this URL gets the correct results: http://localhost:3000/api/skills/category_id/2.  This is my Get:    @Get('/category_id/:id')
  public async getSkillsByCategory(@Param('id') id) {
    return this.skillsService.getSkillsByCategory(id);
  }

Comment: Change to @Get('/category/:id'), restart your app, and try localhost:3000/api/skills/category/2 . It should work, the main here is to pass `:id` parameter.

Comment: I've done that before for you but I just did it again:   GET http://localhost:4200/api/skills/category_id/1 404 (Not Found).   How can your setup work?  'category' does not exist anywhere in my code or the db.  Isn't that part of the URL supposed to be the column name, which does work for me?

Comment: But you are using  localhost:4200/api/skills/category_id/1 this is a wrong URL. Answer to the last quesion. No, it's just a URL, it could be `category`, or `category_id`, or whatever valid. Here `:id` is important, it is the same as in express. Please loo at, https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html (Route parameters). So when you are writing @Get('category/:id') what really matters is :id. Because your id for getting category is extracting from it.

Comment: localhost:4200 is on the front end before the proxy and shows in the console for Angular.  This is the URL the server sees:   http://localhost:3000/api/skills/category_id/2.   The proxy setup works for all CRUD.  Notice at the top of my post that I'm using localhost:3000.  So that isn't an issue.  I don't see in the Express doc that I can use any string I can imagine in that part of the URI.  You seem to be saying that I could use /skills/arf/2 and it should work.  (I tried it in Postman, it doesn't)  How could express know what column I want to query?  The path has to be real.